# What do the Arabic dialogues in the League of Extraordinary Gentlemen say?

Tags: languages, league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen

At the very beginning of Alan Moore's League of Extraordinary Gentlemen, there is this scene where Miss Murray goes to Cairo and there we have some dialogues in Arabic, with no translation. I can work out pretty much what is going on from the panels, but what exactly is being said there?

Comment: Is there a video ? I speak arabic and can provide detailed translation.

Comment: @yondaime008 no, I don't think there is

Comment: well i see there's a full transcript as answer so i guess that's not required anymore, has been a while since i watched that movie, I'll try to catch it again sometime and verify the content, since arabic is my mother tongue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [a transcription](http://www.enjolrasworld.com/Jess%20Nevins/League%20of%20Extraordinary%20Gentlemen/Notes%20on%20League%20of%20Extraordinary%20Gentlemen%201.htm) with the Arabic translated into English which I *think* is what you're looking for:

> **Page 5. Panel 2.** We're in an opium den; those long instruments the men are holding are opium pipes.
>
> Thanks to Daniel Nogly, I can now provide an Arabic translation of the following pages.
>
> *Guide:* "Who's staying here, Miss?"
>
> **Panel 3.** *Guide:* "Whom are you you seeking here?"
>
> *Murray:* "Thank you for your great help."
>
> **Page 6. Panel 2.** Ms. Murray is speaking to Allan Quatermain
>
> [...]
>
> **Panel 11.** *Mina:* "Get off!" *Guide:* "Come here, woman! We are not that ugly. That's just a glass <sub>1</sub>. You won't feel a thing."
>
> **Panel 12.** *Fat Guy:* "Come on...be nice to us."
>
> **Page 7. Panel 1.** *Slim Guy:* "You are going to like this. We are his darlings [favourites]."
>
> **Panel 3.** *Slim Guy:* "...yes, that´s better."
>
> **Panel 4.** *Slim Guy:* "I swear to God."
>
> **Panel 5.** *Quatermain:* "That´s enough!"
>
> **Panel 6.** *Quatermain:* "...leave her alone or I´ll crack your heads open."
>
> **Panel 7.** *Fat Guy:* "...he´s exaggerating ...just look at him. He´s a destroyer." <sup>2</sup>
>
> *Slim Guy:* "You live like a dead man. Among gnats."
>
> **Panel 8.** *Slim Guy:* "I´ll make a gnat out of you."
>
> [...]
>
> **Panel 12.** *Fat Guy:* "Son of a bitch, you killed my brother... I´ll tear your heart apart."
>
> **Page 8. Panel 1.** *Fat Guy:* "You damned English...dirty..."
>
> **Panel 2.** *Fat Guy:* "Son of a whore!"
>
> **Panel 3.** *Fat Guy:* "You'll not stay tired.You are going to..."
>
> **Panel 4.** *Fat Guy:* "...die?"
>
> **Panel 8.** *Fat Guy:* "My friends, they have killed me! ....don´t let them escape!"
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1</sup> What the "glass" comment might be is unclear; Daniel Nogly's translator said that it meant specifically a "wine glass."
>
> <sup>2</sup> I'm assuming that "he's a destroyer" is a phrase for an opium addict.

Answer (score 5):

There's a full translation in [Jess Nevin's annotations](http://www.enjolrasworld.com/Jess%20Nevins/League%20of%20Extraordinary%20Gentlemen/Notes%20on%20League%20of%20Extraordinary%20Gentlemen%201.htm) (which no League reader should miss). The dialogue doesn't add much information to the visuals so I won't reproduce it all here, but one bit on page 7 sticks out:

Panel 7:

> You live like a dead man. Among gnats.

Panel 8:

> I'll make a gnat out of you.

Comment: I get a  404 error on the link

Comment: @Shevliaskovic Heck, I pasted it wrong. Well, it's the same link as in the other answer; you didn't miss anything.